# Android Calendar: Recurring event is continuing for all the month but I need to repeat it on certain dates in every month

Tags: android, calendar, recurring-events

I'm loading both recurring event and one-time events to the calendar. One-time event is working fine but in recurring event the events are continuing to the next days, I had given recurrence rule as
`values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,"FREQ=MONTHLY;"+"BYMONTHDAY"+"=" + type + ";");` like this (Here for `type` I'm passing dates in which event have to repeat). Below is the snippet of the code and an image of output 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjx3j.png)

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events._ID, id);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, eventStart.getTime());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=MONTHLY;" + "BYMONTHDAY" + "=" + type + ";");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P" + eventEnd.getTime() + "S");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, name);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.parseColor("#03A9F4"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Instances.BEGIN` 
instead `Events.DTSTART`